# Is the question requiring the use of a gamma or exponential distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

Incoming telephone calls to an operator are assumed to be a Poisson process with
parameter $\lambda$. Find the density function of the length of time for $n$ calls to be received, and find the mean time and variance of the random variable of the length of time for $n$ calls.

Comment: Note that depending on the parameters, the gamma distribution is an exponential distribution. (when the shape parameter of the gamma is $\alpha=1$)

Comment: So.. your question is basically "do this problem for me?"

Comment: nope, i was actually confused

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of several ways to define this process is that the arrival times (length of time from one incoming call to the next) are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) Exponential random variables with rate parameter $\lambda$, which implies a mean of $1\over{\lambda}$ (at least the way I parameterize the exponential).

Then the time of the  $n$th arrival has a Gamma($n$, $\lambda$) distribution, since the sum of  $n$  i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ is a Gamma($n$, $\lambda$).  You can then use the properties of these distribution to find your answer.